# How do I prevent custom circle cursor to add scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a little problem. I'm trying to add a custom cursor the my wordpress website.

With js and css I managed to add a circle an animation on hover to my cursor. But when the custom cursor with a circle reaches the end of the page, a scrollbar is revealing.

How can I prevent that?

JS

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
   cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+(e.pageY - 40)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX - 40)+"px;")
})

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
$('.cursor').addClass('zooming');
  }).on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
$(".cursor").removeClass("zooming")
  });
```

CSS

```
.cursor {
  z-index: 20;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition:  transform .2s cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    -moz-transition:  transform .2s cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    -ms-transition:  transform .2s cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    -o-transition:  transform .2s cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    transition:  transform .2s cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.275);
    transform-origin: center center;
}
.zooming.cursor {
  background-color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border:none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(.3);
    -o-transform: scale(.3);
    transform: scale(.3);
}
```

Comment: Add html as well..

Comment: What part exactly to prevent the scroll?